# bytes.String() vs bytes.Bytes() in Go

Tags: go

Consider a text file like this:

```
Some text
here.
---
More text
another line.
---
Third part of text.
```

I want to split it into three parts, divided by the `---` separator. The parts should be stored in a map.

Now, the exact same programs with different types.

When I use `string`, everything works fine:

```
KEY: 0
Some text
here.
KEY: 1
More text
another line.
KEY: 2
Third part of text.
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IcGdoUNcTEe

When I use `[]byte`, things gets messed up:

```
KEY: 0
Third part of teKEY: 1
Third part of text.
ne.
KEY: 2
Third part of text.
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jqLhCrqsvOs

Why?

---

Program 1 (`string`):

```
func main() {
    parts := parseParts([]byte(input))

    for k, v := range parts {
        fmt.Printf("KEY: %d\n%s", k, v)
    }
}

func parseParts(input []byte) map[int]string {
    parts := map[int]string{}
    s := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(input))
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    i := 0
    for s.Scan() {
        if s.Text() == "---" {
            parts[i] = buf.String()
            buf.Reset()
            i++
            continue
        }
        buf.Write(s.Bytes())
        buf.WriteString("\n")
    }
    parts[i] = buf.String()
    return parts
}
```

---

Program 2 (`[]byte`):

```
func main() {
    parts := parseParts([]byte(input))

    for k, v := range parts {
        fmt.Printf("KEY: %d\n%s", k, v)
    }
}

func parseParts(input []byte) map[int]string {
    parts := map[int]string{}
    s := bufio.NewScanner(bytes.NewReader(input))
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    i := 0
    for s.Scan() {
        if s.Text() == "---" {
            parts[i] = buf.String()
            buf.Reset()
            i++
            continue
        }
        buf.Write(s.Bytes())
        buf.WriteString("\n")
    }
    parts[i] = buf.String()
    return parts
}
```

Comment: Please edit the source code into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the string version,

```
parts[i] = buf.String()
```

sets `parts[i]` to a new string every time.  In the `[]byte` version,

```
parts[i] = buf.Bytes()
```

sets `parts[i]` to a byte slice backed by the same array every time.  The contents of the backing array are the same for all three slices, but the lengths match the length when created, which is why all three slices show the same content but cut off at different places.

You could replace the byte slice line

```
parts[i] = buf.Bytes()
```

with something like this:

```
bb := buf.Bytes()
b := make([]byte, len(bb))
copy(b, bb)
parts[i] = b
```

in order to get the behavior to match the string version.  But the string version is easier and better matches what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `bytes.Buffer.String` copies the memory, while `bytes.Buffer.Bytes` does not. Quoting the [documentation](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.Bytes),

> The slice is valid for use only until the next buffer modification (that is, only until the next call to a method like Read, Write, Reset, or Truncate).